# Meteor Publish Distinct Values of Field in Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm stuck on a pretty simple scenario in Meteor:

- I have a huge collection of things with many fields, some of them containing quite a bit of text.
- I want to create a page for searching that collection.
- One of the fields that each item in the collection has is "category".
- I'd like to give the user the ability to filter by that category.
- For that, I need to publish just the distinct values of the category field in the collection.

I can't figure out a way to do that without publishing the whole collection which takes way too long. How can I publish just the distinct categories and use them to fill a dropdown?

Bonus question and somewhat related: How do I publish a count of all items in the collection without publishing the whole collection?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point to make this easier would be to normalize your `categories` into a separate database collection.

However assuming that is not possible or practical, the best (though imperfect) solution will be to publish two separate versions of your collection, one which returns only the `categories` field of the entire collection and another which returns all fields of the collection for the selected category only. That would look like the following:

```
// SERVER
Meteor.startup(function(){

  Meteor.publish('allThings', function() {

    // return only id and categories field for all your things 
    return Things.find({}, {fields: {categories: 1}});

  });

  Meteor.publish('thingsByCategory', function(category) {

    // return all fields for things having the selected category
    // you can then subscribe via something like a client-side Session variable
    // e.g., Meteor.subscribe("thingsByCategory", Session.get("category"));

    return Things.find({category: category});
  });
});
```

Note that you will still need to assemble your array of categories client side from the Things cursor (for example, by using underscore's _.pluck and _.uniq methods to grab the categories and remove any dups). But the data set will be much smaller as you are only working with single-field documents now.

(Note that ideally, you would want to use Mongo's distinct() method in your publish function to publish only the distinct categories, but that is not possible directly as it returns an array which cannot be published).

Comment: Doesn't really address what the question was specifically asking. How to do this without publishing the entire collection?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the internal `this._documents.collectionName` to only send new categories down to the client.  Tracking which categories to remove becomes a bit ugly so you probably will still end up maintaining a separate 'categories' collection eventually.

Example:

```
Meteor.publish( 'categories', function(){
  var self = this;
  largeCollection.find({},{fields: {category: 1}).observeChanges({
    added: function( id, doc ){
      if( ! self._documents.categories[ doc.category ] ) 
        self.added( 'categories', doc.category, {category: doc.category});         
    },
    removed: function(){
      _.keys( self._documents.categories ).forEach( category ){
        if ( largeCollection.find({category: category},{limit: 1}).count() === 0 )
          self.removed( 'categories', category );
      }
    }
  });

  self.ready();    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: the bonus question, publishing counts: take a look at the meteorite package publish-counts. I think that does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

These patterns might be helpful to you.  Here is a publication that publishes counts:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
/* Counts Publish Function
/*****************************************************************************/

// server: publish the current size of a collection
Meteor.publish("countsByProject", function (arguments) {
  var self = this;

    if (this.userId) {
        var roles = Meteor.users.findOne({_id : this.userId}).roles;
        if ( _.contains(roles, arguments.projectId) ) {

              //check(arguments.video_id, Integer);



              // observeChanges only returns after the initial `added` callbacks
              // have run. Until then, we don't want to send a lot of
              // `self.changed()` messages - hence tracking the
              // `initializing` state.

              Videos.find({'projectId': arguments.projectId}).forEach(function (video) {
                  var count = 0;
                  var initializing = true;
                  var video_id = video.video_id;
                  var handle = Observations.find({video_id: video_id}).observeChanges({
                    added: function (id) {
                      //console.log(video._id);
                      count++;
                      if (!initializing)
                        self.changed("counts", video_id, {'video_id': video_id, 'observations': count});
                    },
                    removed: function (id) {
                      count--;
                      self.changed("counts", video_id, {'video_id': video_id, 'observations': count});
                    }
                    // don't care about changed
                  });



                  // Instead, we'll send one `self.added()` message right after
                  // observeChanges has returned, and mark the subscription as
                  // ready.
                  initializing = false;
                  self.added("counts", video_id, {'video_id': video_id, 'observations': count});
                  self.ready();

                  // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
                  // Stopping a subscription automatically takes
                  // care of sending the client any removed messages.
                  self.onStop(function () {
                    handle.stop();
                  });


              }); // Videos forEach


        } //if _.contains
    } // if userId

  return this.ready();  

});
```

And here is one that creates a new collection from a specific field:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
/* Tags Publish Functions
/*****************************************************************************/

// server: publish the current size of a collection
Meteor.publish("tags", function (arguments) {
  var self = this;

    if (this.userId) {
        var roles = Meteor.users.findOne({_id : this.userId}).roles;
        if ( _.contains(roles, arguments.projectId) ) {

                var observations, tags, initializing, projectId;
                initializing = true;
                projectId = arguments.projectId;
                observations = Observations.find({'projectId' : projectId}, {fields: {tags: 1}}).fetch();
                tags = _.pluck(observations, 'tags');
                tags = _.flatten(tags);
                tags = _.uniq(tags);

                var handle = Observations.find({'projectId': projectId}, {fields : {'tags' : 1}}).observeChanges({
                    added: function (id, fields) {
                      if (!initializing) {
                        tags = _.union(tags, fields.tags);
                        self.changed("tags", projectId, {'projectId': projectId, 'tags': tags});
                      }
                    },
                    removed: function (id) {
                      self.changed("tags", projectId, {'projectId': projectId, 'tags': tags});
                    }
                });

                initializing = false;
                self.added("tags", projectId,  {'projectId': projectId, 'tags': tags});
                self.ready();

                self.onStop(function () {
                    handle.stop();
                });

        } //if _.contains
    } // if userId

  return self.ready();  

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems complicated. Not sure what all the userId/roles stuff has to do with my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested it on Meteor, and according to the replies, I'm getting skeptical that it will work but using a mongoDB distinct would do the trick.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: You can't use mongo distinct as-is in Meteor. It's not supported by the Mongo driver.  There's some packages that add this capability but I believe under the hood their just using `_.uniq` trickery on fetched arrays. I don't believe there's currently a good way to get reactive results that are distinct.